# UI Router inline template

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

I'm just trying UI Router for the first time. This is my very simple attempt. So I would now expect, that just the header would display. But the page keeps empty. What am I doing wrong?

```
<!doctype html>
<html ng-app="myApp">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.22/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-ui-router/0.2.14/angular-ui-router.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        var app = angular.module('myApp', ['ui.router']);
        app.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
          $stateProvider.state('index', {
              template: '<h1>Header</h1>'
            });
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <main ui-view></main>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to set - in your example - `$urlRouterProvider`:

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', ['ui.router']);

app.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/');
    $stateProvider.state('index', {
        url : '/',
        template: '<h1>Header</h1>'
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're expecting a state to activate when on a specific url (from pushState or http) you need to specify the url.

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', ['ui.router']);

app.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
    $stateProvider.state('index', {
        url : '/',
        template: '<h1>Header</h1>'
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to set a blank url state for $stateProvider

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', ['ui.router']);
app.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
    $stateProvider
     .state('index', {
        url : '',
        template: '<h1>Header</h1>'
    });
});
```

Plnkr: http://plnkr.co/edit/n3uX2SMR0puNROzRePOO